# ListAdapter Item ViewType

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I have just found the possibilty to determine a type of a list entry with the getItemViewType() of the adpater. Can you provide me with a description on how to use this properly?

Currently I use a custom type integer in the view classes that I use to create the views in the getView() of the list adapter. Is it a better solution to use the built in capbilities of the adapter?

My current code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    IFilterable data = filteredData.get(position);
    if(convertView == null || convertView.getId() != data.getType()) {
        switch(data.getType()) {
            case IReport.SPECIAL_ACTION:
                convertView = new SpecialActionView(context);
                ((SpecialActionView) convertView).set(((SpecialAction) data));
                break;
            case IReport.TRANSFER_DECLARATION:
                convertView = new TransferDeclarationView(context);
                ((TransferDeclarationView) convertView).set(((TransferDeclaration) data));
                break;
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is ok, take a look at [this video](http://d.android.com/videos/index.html#v=wDBM6wVEO70) for more informations.

Comment: i have watched this video but they dont give any code examples on this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't well explain myself, I think there is no better way to do than your code. :/

Comment: I agree, the method you're using right is simple, fast, and - most importantly - works, so I'd stay with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this value is used internally by the UI when recycling views, to reduce the amount of View re-inflation.

You might want to look at [AgendaByDayAdapter.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#b2bXTFUfX1o/src/com/android/calendar/AgendaByDayAdapter.java&q=getItemViewType&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc) for an example of its usage